# Using Long Polling Too Slow in Chrome Tabs

Tags: jquery, long-integer, polling

I need your help.

I'm building a social network, and I'm using Long Polling with PHP for most applications, but I realized that when you open more than one tab in Chrome, the codes are slow and inoperable. With an open flap the code works normally.

Does anyone have a light?

PHP`

```
$timestart = time();
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=social", "social", "senha");
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
if(isset($_POST['timestamp'])){
$timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
}else{
$pega_time = $pdo->prepare("SELECT NOW() as now");
$pega_time->execute();
$row = $pega_time->fetchObject();

$timestamp = $row->now;
}
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT postagens.id as postagem,    n     postagens.likestimestamp FROM postagens WHERE postagens.likestimestamp >    '$timestamp'");
$newData = false;
$postagens = array();
while(!$newData && (time()-$timestart)<15){
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $postagens = $row;
    $newData = true;

       break;
}
 usleep(6000);
 }

$pega_time = $pdo->prepare("SELECT NOW() as now");
$pega_time->execute();
$row = $pega_time->fetchObject();

$timestamp = $row->now;
$data = array('postagens' => $postagens, 'timestamp' => $timestamp);
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

JQUERY

```
pegaLikes();
function pegaLikes(timestamp){
var data = {};

    var texto = {};
if(typeof timestamp != 'undefined') {
    data.timestamp = timestamp;
}

$.post('assets/serverlikes.php', data, function(res){


    for(i in res.postagens){

$.get("tete.php?likes=1&id="+res.postagens[i].postagem, function(result) {        $('#likesnumeros'+res.postagens[i].postagem).html(result);
    });
$.get("like.php?id="+res.postagens[i].postagem, function(result) {      $('#likar'+res.postagens[i].postagem).html(result);

});

}
    pegaLikes(res.timestamp);
}, 'json'); }
```